# Netty server stuck, unable to handle the client request

Tags: java, netty

In our game application developed in netty server 3.2.x.  We are able to play the games normally, but sometimes the netty server is unable to handle the client request.
We have checked the netty server socket connection, and it has connected successfully.
There is no exception raised in this scenario but the server is stuck. Once we restart the server then we are able to play the games.

We have also tried the netty 3.10.x jar, but same problem is raised.

Do we need to configure any bootstrap settings or any other changes needed in the code.

Please give your suggestions.

Code:

```
public void setAddress(String ip, int port) {

Timer timer = new HashedWheelTimer();

ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

    // Set up the pipeline factory.
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory()
    {
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception
        {
            return Channels.pipeline(new AMFDecoder() 
                , new IdleStateHandler(timer, 6, 0, 0)
                , new MessageHandler() // Message handler   
                , new AMFEncoder()); // Message encoder
        }
    });

    // Setup the server options
    bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("reuseAddress", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("sendBufferSize", 32767);
    bootstrap.setOption("receiveBufferSize", 32767);

    addr = new InetSocketAddress(ip, port);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "stuck" instead of "strucked"?

Comment: @jesper, Yes. server stuck.